How to run my ISS tracking script 24/7 on PythonAnywhere?
I have written a Python script that tracks the International Space Station (ISS) using an API and sends me an email if the ISS is overhead and it's nighttime. The script works perfectly on my local machine, but I want to run it 24/7 on PythonAnywhere. Here is the code snippet:
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import smtplib
import time

MY_EMAIL = "myemail"
MY_PASSWORD = "mypassword"

MY_LAT = 52.408054 # Coventry latitude
MY_LONG = -1.510556 # Coventry longitude


def is_iss_overhead():
    response = requests.get(url="http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json")
    response.raise_for_status()
    data = response.json()

    iss_latitude = float(data["iss_position"]["latitude"])
    iss_longitude = float(data["iss_position"]["longitude"])

    #Your position is within +5 or -5 degrees of the ISS position.
    if 47 <= iss_latitude <= MY_LAT + 5 and MY_LAT - 5 <= iss_longitude <= MY_LONG + 5:
        return True


def is_night():
    parameters = {
        "lat": MY_LAT,
        "lng": MY_LONG,
        "formatted": 0,
    }
    response = requests.get("https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json", params=parameters)
    response.raise_for_status()
    data = response.json()
    sunrise = int(data["results"]["sunrise"].split("T")[1].split(":")[0])
    sunset = int(data["results"]["sunset"].split("T")[1].split(":")[0])

    time_now = datetime.now().hour

    if time_now >= sunset or time_now <= sunrise:
        return True


while True:
    time.sleep(60)
    if is_iss_overhead() and is_night():
        connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com")
        connection.starttls()
        connection.login(MY_EMAIL, MY_PASSWORD)
        connection.sendmail(
            from_addr=MY_EMAIL,
            to_addrs=MY_PASSWORD,
            msg="Subject:Look up!\n\nThe ISS is above you in the sky."
        )


# Then send me an email to tell me to look up.
# BONUS: run the code every 60 seconds.

I understand that PythonAnywhere allows for running scripts, but I am not sure how to set it up for continuous execution. Here are my specific questions:
How do I set up the script on PythonAnywhere to run indefinitely?
Are there any considerations regarding the use of external APIs and sending emails through PythonAnywhere that I should be aware of?
Any guidance or step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated.

If that's your real email password, you should go change it now

It already runs forever, every 60 seconds (plus whatever overhead you get from the function calls; probably several seconds at least occasionally).

Separately, unless you are beyond a polar circle, running every minute during the day makes little sense. Get the time until the next sundown and sleep until then. A smaller fix is to change the order of the function calls so you don't abuse the ISS API needlessly when you aren't going to use its result anyway. if is_night() and is_iss_overhead():

The is_night() logic could be optimized nicely with an object which knows the date, and whether it needs to call the remote API to get this information for the next 24 hours (or less elegantly with a bunch of globals if you don't know anything about objects yet).
